# How to remove Default Value on select

Tags: css, select

I'll try with -webkit-appearance:none, outline:none but this issue isn't fix, Please give CSS solution for  remove default value in chrome.[image]

Comment: tried `border: 0px;`?

Comment: what do you mean by default value?

Comment: And please post your code so we can have a further look in this and resolve the issue...

Comment: What did you mean by `default value`? The default appearance on browser?

Comment: Please share a fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```css
select:invalid { color: gray; }
```

```html
<form>
    <select required>
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose...</option>
        <option value="uno">one</option>
        <option value="dos">two</option>
    </select>
</form>
```